# JQuery AJAX : Trying to find errors

Tags: jquery, ajax

So i have an ajax script that is being called whenever i click the button "Delete" that is on a table that has the id "hor-minimalist-b", and it's executing something which is on a php being called in the href.

The php has an error that i made on porpose.
How do i make it call the error instead of making the script keep trying to delete the row?

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#hor-minimalist-b").on("click","a.delete",function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); //prevents from going into another page
            var a= $(this);
            //alert($(this).attr("href"));
            $.ajax({
                url: a.attr("href")//calls the php
                ,error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
                ,success: function (data)
                {
                    alert("Done!");
                    if(data = 1)
                        alert("Error")
                    else
                        a.parents("tr").remove();
                }
            })
        });
    });
    </script>
```

EDIT: Everything has been fixed.

SOLUTION:

```
$(function(){
$("#hor-minimalist-b").on("click","a.delete",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var a= $(this);
    //alert($(this).attr("href"));
    $.ajax({
        url: a.attr("href")
        ,error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }
        ,success: function (data)
        {
            if (data == "sucesso") {
                alert("Sucess!");
                a.parents("tr").remove();
            } else {
                alert('Error!');
            }               
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Need more info. Please post the relevant PHP code.

Comment: A PHP error isn't an error for the ajax call, the call is only erroneous if the request fails. You should handle your PHP errors on the serverside, and just send a message to the success handler that an error occured on the server.

Comment: The PHP has no errors, i made it on purpose because i needed to it to say that there was an error when someone tried to delete that row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enter an unexisting address in `url` and the error function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Does your webserver still answer with HTTP Status 200? Else the error function should get called.
In that case put in the data object the confirmation that the row was successfully deleted and only remove then the row (so reverse the if)

Comment: it is fixed now but i don't think so this only thing i needed to add was an url so that it would imediatelly tell that the error was there thanks tho